# Read appsettings.json from Angular-CLI

Tags: .net, angular

Is there any way to read `appsettings.json` of `.NET Core` from `Angular-CLI`? I do not want to use an API. I want to access the above file **directly**. My problem is I do not know which path to use since it is located inside `serverUrl/Files/`. 
I tried `serverUrl/Files/appsettings.json` but it did not work even if I have             `UseStaticFiles() middleware` in my `Startup.cs`.

Answer (score 0):

As fas as I know if you are using angular-cli only, you can read files (.json, images..) from assets folder (because when angular-cli build the application make a copy of this folder in dist). So, I'am afraid that you only can load files from this folder

If you want to read this values from .NET Core, you can read it from startUp function.
Imagine your appsetting.json is like

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AppSettings": {
    "NewProperty": {
      "oneProperty": "value one",
      "twoProperty": "value two"
    }
  }
}
```

you can use

```
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
     ...

    IConfigurationSection newPropertySection =
        Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:NewProperty");

    IEnumerable<IConfigurationSection> newPropertySectionMembers = 
          newPropertySection.GetChildren();

    foreach (var item in newPropertySectionMembers)
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

NOTE: I using .NET Core 2.1

Comment: Can I pass the above values to Angular?